# What's happening to this plant?

Tags: diseases, leaves

[image]
It is on a balcony sun exposed. This brown dots started to appear, any Idea on what it can be?

Comment: The holly is supposed to be a variegated form, correct?

Comment: Yes it is, it is in a pot

Comment: Has it been suddenly directly sun exposed?

Comment: @ColinBeckingham not suddenly it was on a balgony for entire winter, and now day by day it receive more sun...